# Importing a ragged array while ignoring rows that start with "#"

Tags: import

I am new to *Mathematica*, and I find that there may be a lot of ways of doing this.
I was wondering which one might be the most general.

I am importing data from `.txt` files, resulting in a ragged array due to many lines containing parameters and other comments which I want to ignore.
I just want to import the numbers, and ignore the comments.

I am using this:

```
Import["filename.txt", "TSV", "HeaderLines" -> 15]
```

I have no TrailerLines that I need to skip, however, there are many rows halfway through the data which I would like to remove. These lines all start with `#`, which makes me think that there is a way to just specify that any line starting with `#` be skipped.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who might be able to help me with this.

Comment: Duplicate: [21075](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21075).  Related: [2655](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2655), [29384](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29384)

Comment: I'd be tempted to use [`DefineImportStreamMethod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/StreamMethods.html) to do this, but it's use becomes more complex: you have to open the stream first with the method, and then use `Import`. But, `Import`'s ability to use streams is undocumented, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about the duplicate question. I was not searching correctly I think. And thanks a lot to all for the help.

Comment: @CSR I didn't find it at first, either. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete them after `Import`.

```
DeleteCases[Import["filename.txt", "Data", "HeaderLines" -> 10], {_String, ___}]
```

or more precisely

```
DeleteCases[Import["filename.txt", "Data", "HeaderLines" -> 10],
  {_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "#*"] &), ___}]
```